# Removing dependency on a specific vulnerable package

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core, package, .net-5, jfrog-xray

According to a recent JFrog Xray scan, our application (.NET 5) has a "critical" vulnerability due to a dependency on a specific version of Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms. There is a newer version of the package with the vulnerability resolved that I want my project to use instead. The problem I'm having is that this is not a package that we've explicitly added to the project, but rather a dependency that some other packages have, so simply adding the newer version of the package to the project isn't enough to remove the dependency entirely; I can still see references to the "bad" version appearing in project.assets.json. Upgrading to the latest version of the top-level packages has helped, but has still left some references to the "bad" version of Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms via dependencies of dependencies of dependencies.

E.g, we're using the very latest version of Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, but this has a dependency on System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter, which has a dependency on the "bad" Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms.

TLDR; I want to be able to tell my project "If you have a dependency on this package anywhere in your dependency tree, don't use version X, use version Y instead", but I'm not sure if there exists a way to do this.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue with our solution. Did you ever find a resolution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change what version of a library your dependencies use because that could easily introduce breaking changes. This is the modern version of [DLL hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell).

The answer is to update the library that has the old dependency. If it's open source, you can do this yourself and use your forked version with the updated dependencies. If you don't have access to the source then you will have to contact the developer and tell them about the vulnerability.

If the developer is Microsoft, godspeed.